# Joda-time: Hibernate Mapping Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, jodatime

I have a grails-app. The domain classes could be User, Behavior etc.
The User has many Behaviors and the Behavior belongs to User. The Behavior model includes a Date which is DateCreated.

There is a need to change the type of time/date used in the project. I have to set Joda-Time and set all the Date into DateTime.

I checked this link to get inside about dateCreated: https://grails.org/wiki/JodaTime%20Plugin

In my build.gradle file I have added:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:1.4'
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
```

In my Behavior class I added the following part:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.*

    class Behavior {

        DateTime dateCreated
        static mapping = {
            dateCreated type: PersistentDateTimeTZ, {
                column name: "dateCreated_timestamp"
                column name: "dateCreated_zone"
            }
        }
    }
```

However I get the following error and I do not know how to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.p.r.b.user.User, at table: behavior, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]
```

Please can anyone give me an idea what is going on?
Any explanation or comment is very much appreciated!

Comment: The exception is: "MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.philips.research.bce.user.User, at table: behavior". Is that the right stack trace? Sounds like an object called "User" is not mapped.

Comment: I changed only the Date type of the Behavior object. A User has many Behaviors. When I add a Behavior to a User and I do user.save(), I get this problem, that the user can not be mapped